# Touch gestures on Flash Builder AIR simulator

Tags: ios, flash, touch

I want to test my iOS app on AIR mobile device simulator. When I run this code on AIR:

```
trace(Multitouch.supportsTouchEvents);
```

I get false(on iPhone 4 of course I get true).
Is there a way to enable touch gestures on AIR?

(I'm using Flash Builder 4.7)

Answer (score -2):

Use this code of file named build.xml with [ANT platform](http://www.stasha.info/index.php?id=76) for RUN:

```
<project name="HAB" default="run" basedir=".">
<property name="SDK_HOME" value="C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash CC/AIR3.8"/>
<property name="FLASH_HOME" value="C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash CC"/>
<property name="ADL" value="${SDK_HOME}/bin/adl.exe"/>
<property name="SIM" value="${FLASH_HOME}/Common/Configuration/simulator/SimController.exe"/>
<property name="APP_NAME" value="HAB"/>
<property name="APP_DESCRIPTOR" value="${APP_NAME}-app.xml"/>
<target name="run">
 <exec executable="${SIM}" dir="./bin-debug" spawn="true">
    <arg line="-once"/>
    <arg line="-lang en_US"/>
    <arg line="-port 7840"/>
 </exec>
 <exec executable="${ADL}" dir="./">
    <arg line="-profile extendedMobileDevice"/>
    <arg line="-nodebug"/>
    <arg line="-Xsimulation 7840"/>
    <arg line="${APP_DESCRIPTOR}"/>
 </exec> 
</target>
</project>
```

but i really don't know how to debug actionscript code with ANT

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to the question

Comment: it enables touch simulator in flash builder